# How to get Windows 10 Build version in JAVA

Tags: java, regex, windows

Is there an simple way to get Windows OS build version (like 16299, 15063 etc) in JAVA? 
[image]

Currently only solution I've found is running external process and parsing the output:

```
 Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process process;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String stdOutLine = null;
    String windowsVersion = null;

    try {
        process = runtime.exec("cmd.exe /c ver");
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        while ((stdOutLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(stdOutLine);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error while getting Windows version");
    }
    windowsVersion = Arrays.stream(stringBuilder.toString().split("\\."))
            .filter(s -> s.length() == 5 && s.matches("[0-9]+"))
            .findFirst()
            .get();
```

Is there another more elegant way of either getting that string or extracting the needed part? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As Java is platform-independent, it has no API to get information specific to a certain platform.
However, If you know how to do it in C, you could use [JNI](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html).